# How to fetch values from a column where extension should be .jpg only?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to display records from a column whose has only ".Jpg" Extension
How can I do so is sql query.
Any help would be helpful

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I have url path in db column from there I need to retrieve only path whose extension will be .jpg

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: SQL Server 2008 reached end of life already. I would strongly recommend to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can make use of wildcard operations in SQL using like clause. % in below represents the name of the file and will pull all records with .jpg extension.

```
select * from table_name where column_name like '%.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use function CHARINDEX().
The CHARINDEX() function searches for a substring in a string, and returns the position.

If the substring is not found, this function returns 0. It's more better than LIKE especially when you have spaces and other symbols in your column.

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE
 CHARINDEX('.jpg', column-name) >0
```